# Can I save object to disk without serialization?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know whether it is possible to save an instance of some class to file on my disk and then recover it without serialization . For example converting the instance to byte array and then saving in FileStream or something else. Honestly, I am asking since not fully understand why we need serialization if we can save objects to files without it?

Comment: Do you need to read this object back? If so, how you know which type instance you should create?

Comment: In C you could do that if you don't have pointers in your structure. In C# everything is pointers, so yes, you can write an object to disk, but that would only make sense with value types. If you write other objects to disk you just write pointer values which are meaningless once the program has ended.

Comment: @Fabio, but with serialization we also need to know type of the instance to deserialize. At least I see this in deserialization examples

Comment: Converting an object to a data structure that can be stored or transferred is literally the definition of serialization, so your question comes down to "can I do serialization without serialization?". Do you maybe want to avoid some specific forms of serialization? (like the human readable ones json/xml/etc)

Comment: @Knoop, kind of. I am interested more whether something similar to byte[] arr = (byte[])object and then putting these bytes to FileStream can replace serialization techniques.

Comment: When you save data to a file you need a format so when you read you can parse data the same way it was saved.  Serialization is a format for saving data and then you can read by deserializing.  The are lots of different formats that you can save/read from a file.

Comment: @DenysAlexieiev - Read - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.5

Comment: @DenysAlexieiev Even if you convert it to a byte array and store that it is still called serialization. That said there are a lot of different formats you can serialize to and from and those formats also include binary options. Though I've not worked with it myself I advise you to take a look at google's protobuf: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) of serialization says: In computing, serialization (or serialisation) is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that **can be stored** (for example, in a file or memory buffer) or transmitted (for example, across a network connection link) and reconstructed later (possibly in a different computer environment).

Answer is NO, because definition of serialization.